# In jQuery how to select all other parent li of not clicked anchor?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following simple nav links and I want to make sure when I click on any of the links, the "active" class is removed from all other li except the one that was just clicked. In jQuery how can I setup my selector to achieve this?

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `$(this).closest('li').siblings().removeClass('active')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my take on this...

```js
$(function() {
  $('.nav li a').on('click', function() {
    $('.nav li').removeClass('active'); // remove active class from all 
    $(this).closest('li').addClass('active'); // add active classs to element clicked
  });
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="#">Link 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Link 2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 4</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
$('li').click(function() {
  var clicked = this;
  $(this).siblings('li').each(function() {
    if (this !== clicked) {
      $(this).removeClass('active');
    }
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".nav").on("click","li", function(){
   $(".nav li").removeClass('active')
   $(this).addClass('active')
})
```

Comment: $(".nav").on("click","li", function(){
      $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active')
})

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to use the .siblings method for that.

see https://api.jquery.com/siblings/

It even has an example with a list.